# Trying to connect to a taxii server, but i can't import anything

Tags: python

so i'm trying to import a taxii2client server but it's not recognising anything. I've checked and python is correctly installed, i've tried an absolute path to the file location, i've tried to reinstall everything and i can't help but feel like i'm missing something obvious.
please bear in mind that i am only just starting out with python.
the only code i currently have in my program is just an import:

**"from taxii2client.v20 import Server"**

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you haven't installed the module.

You can do this with pip in a terminal window:

`pip install taxii2-client`